# joomla 1.5 admin folder token

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to harden the admin login on a Joomla 1.5+ site and though the client may go for an upgrade soon- it hasn't happened yet.  I edited the administrator/index.php with this code:

```
/* Block access to administrator
--------------------------------------------- */
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$secretkey = 'mytoken';
$redirectto = 'location: http://www.myurl.com';
$usertype = 'Registered';

//Check if the user is not logged in or if is not a super user:
if ($user->guest) { //|| (!$user->guest && $user->usertype == $usertype) ) {
//Check if the secret key is present on the url:
if (@$_GET['access'] != $secretkey) { header($redirectto); }
}
/* --------------------------------------------- */
```

This was based on someones code which I found on the web. Currently, typing www.myurl.com/administrator/ or www.myurl.com/administrator/index.php redirects to the homepage. www.myurl.com/administrator/index.php?access=mytoken displays the login. The number of login attempts has gone down but the RSFirewall! component still reports several a day.

Before I commented the 2nd half of the first if statement the code always redirected no mater what..

How are they still accessing the login page?  And what could I do better?

Comment: Try move the "if (@$_GET['access'] != $secretkey) { header($redirectto); }" line above the getUser() method.

Comment: That would prevent anyone from logging in..  are you suggesting moving the GET['access'] if, to say below the $user->guest if so that it is only testing for the token and not the user status? I believe that would also in effect break the admin panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hacking the core why not use one of the many plugins available that provide this functionality?

On the current [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/) ([JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/)) many of the products listed in "[Login Protection](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection/)" have Joomla 1.5 versions, or failing that try the [Archived JED](http://archive.extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection) (for Joomla 1.5 extensions) you could try the [Login Protection](http://archive.extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection) section.

If your code is after the `onAfterInitialise` event in `/administrator/index.php` then the firewall software will probably still log the access. The `onAfterInitialise` event is the first place an extension can "plug-in" to the Joomla! environment.

To avoid any extensions at all you probably need your code before this block:

```
// trigger the onAfterInitialise events
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterInitialise') : null;
$mainframe->triggerEvent('onAfterInitialise');
```

The various security plugin usually attach themselves to this event and order themselves first with very low or even negative values which is why they work without the firewall getting to see the issue.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. This site has core hacks from long ago. The Backend token plugin does basically the same as the code above- I may install that. However, my question was about the code above. Particularly, how they were still finding the login page at all.

Comment: Good question @cppl

administrator/index.php
Almost at the end of the file right before:


`    echo JResponse::toString($mainframe->getCfg('gzip'));
?>`
I don't believe there are any other hacks in that file.

Comment: Ok, your firewall is probably using `onAfterInitialise` to hook into Joomla see my updated answer.

Comment: Did seem to lower the hits. I only got one notification in almost 24hrs. Certainly it's better than the 10-20 I was getting. Still wish I understood how its possible for them to get to the admin login at all. Seems like this should be killing it..

Comment: tested for a few days here and the number of false logins has dropped off almost completely. Thanks!

Comment: After some testing and thought, I'm guessing the "login" hits are false. After making the final change above, it always throws me out to the home page after I push the login button and I'm guessing between me and the other (non-savy) admin that a refresh or extra button push is causing the misc hits. Thanks again.